# Content provider that shares files

Tags: android, file, android-contentprovider

I am trying to create content provider that share its files with other app. I have searched online but most of the example are using sqlite.  I know how to share data which is in sqlite . but i dont know how to share file using content provider .

Can anyone please share code of content provider that share files with explanation

Comment: Use a FileProvider: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html